# QObject: no such slot QThread::readyRead()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I am trying to figure out how to correctly use Qt TCP Sockets, as well as multithreading. I want, as a test project in support of something more complex but similar I will try in the future, to do the following: a simple application that either listens for exactly one incoming connection, or connects to a serversocket; next it prints everything it receives over that socket.

The situation where I connect to a serversocket (I use netcat with the -l option for this) works fine: everything netcat sends to my application is printed correctly. However, when I use my program to listen for that one incoming connection (generated by netcat), the connecting succeeds but then I get this runtime error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QThread::readyRead() in ..\QTcpTest\listener.cpp:8
```

Here is the entire code (don't mind the plain C I/O I use sometimes, I'll remove this later):

[ main.cpp ]

```
#include "peer.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool askIfServer();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Peer *p;
    int rval;
    if (askIfServer())
        p = new Peer;
    else
        p = new Peer(false);
    rval = a.exec();
    delete p;
    return rval;
}

static bool askIfServer()
{
    bool isServer;
    char ibuf[BUFSIZ];

    fputs("Choose \'host\' or \'join\': ", stderr);
    fgets(ibuf, BUFSIZ, stdin);
    ibuf[strlen(ibuf) - 1] = '\0';
    fflush(stdin);

    if (strcmp(ibuf, "host") == 0)
        isServer = true;
    else if (strcmp(ibuf, "join") == 0)
        isServer = false;
    else
    {
        fputs("Failure.\n", stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }

    return isServer;
}
```

[ peer.h ]

```
#ifndef PEER_H
#define PEER_H

#include "listener.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>

class Peer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static const quint16 PORT = 5483;
    explicit Peer(bool isHost = true, QString hostname = "localhost", QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void acceptPeer();
private:
    bool _isHost;
    QTcpServer *_server;
    QTcpSocket *_socket;
    QThread *_lThread;
    Listener *_listener;
};

#endif // PEER_H
```

[ peer.cpp ]

```
#include "peer.h"

Peer::Peer(bool isHost, QString hostname, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    _isHost(isHost)
{
    if (_isHost)
    {
        _server = new QTcpServer;
        connect(_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(acceptPeer()));
        _server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, PORT);
    }
    else
    {
        _socket = new QTcpSocket;
        connect(_socket, SIGNAL(hostFound()), this, SLOT(acceptPeer()));
        _socket->connectToHost(hostname, PORT);
    }
}

void Peer::acceptPeer()
{
    disconnect(this, SLOT(acceptPeer()));
    if (_isHost)
    {
        _socket = _server->nextPendingConnection();
        delete _server;
        _server = NULL;
    }

    _lThread = new QThread;
    _listener = new Listener(_socket);
    _listener->moveToThread(_lThread);
    _lThread->start();
}
```

[ listener.h ]

```
#ifndef LISTENER_H
#define LISTENER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
using std::cout;

class Listener : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Listener(QTcpSocket *socket, QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void acceptData();
private:
    QTcpSocket *_socket;
};

#endif // LISTENER_H
```

[ listener.cpp ]

```
#include "listener.h"

Listener::Listener(QTcpSocket *socket, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    _socket(socket)
{
    // I guess this is where it goes wrong
    connect(_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(acceptData()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void Listener::acceptData()
{
    QByteArray data = _socket->readAll();
    cout << data.constData();
}
```

The thing I do not get is that the error message claims that I try to connect some signal from QThread (and I clearly do not: see listener.cpp:8); even stranger is that this only happens when the socket is created by the QTcpServer instance, not in the other case. What am I missing?

### EDIT: SOLVED

See my own answer.

Comment: To begin with, rather than adding <QNetwork/...> add qt += network to your .pro file, then you can access the network objects directly; #include <QTcpServer> etc.

Comment: your QThread leaks, add a done signal to peer and connect it to QThreads quit and deleteLater, then also connect it to Peers deleteLater

Comment: You say you want to use multithreading, but QTcpSocket is asynchronous, so you don't really need to create a new thread and move the Listener to it when a new connection is received.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the QThread, you were right I do not need it. Connecting to a server still works fine, but hosting now crashes the program once the constructor of Listener is called (actual crash, no runtime error message in the console).

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use an extra thread anymore (see comment). The problem was deleting the QTcpServer instance in `Peer::acceptPeer()`, once a connection was established. I thought that I could delete it because I only need that one socket `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()` returns. Apparently this is wrong, the socket is probably destroyed as well, leaving me with a rogue pointer (I think) crashing the program. Now I only call `_server->pauseAccepting();` right after I get the socket, and all works fine.

Here is the change I've made:

```
void Peer::acceptPeer()
{
    disconnect(this, SLOT(acceptPeer()));
    if (_isHost)
    {
        _socket = _server->nextPendingConnection();
        _server->pauseAccepting(); // no deletion
    }

    _listener = new Listener(_socket);
}
```